# Cambiar posicion a los elementos de un arreglo PHP

Tags: php

Buenas mi problema es el siguiente tengo este arreglo

```
Array(
[Codigo] => TOTAL
[Descripcion] => 
[L1] => 45
[L2] => 50
[L3] => 40
[total] => 136
[web] => 1
[CDC+CI] => 130)
```

necesito que [CDC+CI] esté antes del [total] les agradeceria mucho la ayuda

Comment: Hola William , habías intentado alguna forma, agrega el código en tu pregunta,puede ser que alguien más tenga la misma inquietud, saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion [array_reverse](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-reverse.php):

```
$nuevo_array = array_reverse($array);
```

de esta forma invertirias el orden de los elementos en el array:

```
CDC+CI  =>  130
web =>  1
total   =>  136
L3  =>  40
L2  =>  50
L1  =>  45
Descripcion =>  
Codigo  =>  TOTAL
```

pero **si deseas mover un elemento especifico dentro del array a otra posición dentro del array**, puedes usar la función [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-splice.php):

```
function moverElement0(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $p1 = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
    $p2 = array_splice($array, 0, $b);
    $array = array_merge($p2,$p1,$array);
}
```

por ejemplo mover el elemento indice 7 a la primera posición

```
moverElemento($array, 7, 0);
```

para obtener:

```
CDC+CI  =>  130
Codigo  =>  TOTAL
Descripcion =>  
L1  =>  45
L2  =>  50
L3  =>  40
total   =>  136
web =>  1
```

Comment: muuuuchas gracias me ahorraste líneas de codigo